# FormatException using String.Format on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFdP3_TF7Ks) tutorial on youtube and at 3h 47 mins I have entered the code (created in console application template), however it is giving me a FormatExcpetion, see:

[image: Screenshot]

I am running visual studio 2015, fully updated.

```
namespace Strings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myString = " It was the best of times, it was the worst of times ";
            myString = string.Format("Length before: {0} -- After: {1)", 
                myString.Length, 
                myString.Trim().Length);

            Console.WriteLine(myString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide details about the error.

Comment: `{1)` should be `{1}`

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.formatexception" occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional infdormation: inpout string was not in correct format.              However this tutorial was written by a pro , dont understand why it wont work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in this line:

```
"Length before: {0} -- After: {1)"
```

It should be like this

```
"Length before: {0} -- After: {1}"
```

You get the exception because you are passing in two parameters but your string only supports one (only `{0}` is correctly formatted)

Comment: @mrpjspencer if this answer helped you, please consider making it the accepted answer, a common practice in SO

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing `}` character on your second string format parameter.